# how can insert new file in apk?

Tags: java, android, apk

I want an apk that install another apk I don't have source of it I want extract my apk with win rar and replace the second apk that is in assets directory and then compress it and rename with apk extension and install on my device
but when this is extract and again zipped I can not install it
it throws `package parsing error`.

Why?

Can I insert new file in apk?

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
            resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            resultIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "myapp.apk")),"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivity(resultIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put add/remove files from the apk manually or using

aapt add MyApp.apk file1 file2 (as ritwik verma noted)

then however you need to sign it with your key as you probably do not know the original key, then however you will get 2 signatures and can have issues.
so when you add your new files you should:

1. in the apk remove META-INF dir
2. sign the apk`jarsigner -keystore "C:\data\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android "C:\data\Some.apk" androiddebugkey`
3. zipalign the apk `zipalign -f 4 "C:\datasome.apk" "C:\data\some_signed.apk"`

jarsigner is part of JDK
zipalign is part of Android SDK

in this example i use the default debug key for andorid you can use yours instead.

Answer (score 0):

An apk is a jar which is a zip. So you can use any tool that manipulates zips.

There is an added complication however: the Android platform requires all files in the apk (except for the files in the MANIFEST directory) to be signed. So you need to call jarsigner again to sign all packages. You should then also call zipalign again.

You must sign the modified apk with the same key that was used to sign the original apk. This is the whole point of the signature: it indicates that the package has not been tampered with without the approval of the signer. (Actually, you can sign with a different key, but then you won't be able to access any data that was produced by the original application or vice versa.)

The ant scripts provided with the Android development kit contain automation to run jarsigner and zipalign.

Alternatively, There's a tool called aapt that is bundled with the Android SDK. You can use it to add/remove/list files in an existing apk. Run aapt without any params and it will print usage instructions. To add a file use:

aapt add MyApp.apk file1 file2 ...

Answer (score 0):

There are tools which allow you to modify an APK on device, however I would recommend finding another way to do this as it's pretty bad practice for anything other than development and experimentation.

You should be able to find the tools you're looking for on the Google play store.